# Install pthread in Ubuntu 18.04 with php5.6

Tags: php, lamp

I need to install pthread in PHP 5.6.

My current LAMP develop environment is.

Xubuntu 18.04

PHP 5.6 (Active. This is the one am using.)

PHP 7.2

Apache2

I have both versions of PHP installed, but I need pthread on PHP 5.6 for development purposes...

Any idea?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you install PHP 5.6?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I followed this tutorial: https://tecadmin.net/install-php5-on-ubuntu/